# deadlock in a process, Unix command?

Tags: multithreading, unix

I was trying to figure out how to know if the threads of a process have been deadlocked on Unix/Linux machine? Also, is there a command for knowing what stage (or status) a process is in? If you know of any tools, please suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a tool that traces system calls, e.g `strace` on Linux or `tusc` on HP-UX. When a deadlock occured, you should see the process hang in the blocking call. That's not a positive proof, though. It might be a regular block. You then need to determine whether the block may be resolved some time or not. This requires knowledge of the resource the process is waiting for.

#### Example

On RHEL4 there exists a... peculiarity... that may cause `ctime` to deadlock. Find an example program exhibiting this behaviour below:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

volatile char *r;

void handler(int sig)
{
    time_t t;

    time(&t);
    r = ctime(&t);
}

int main()
{
    struct itimerval it;
    struct sigaction sa;
    time_t t;
    int counter = 0;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

    it.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    it.it_value.tv_usec = 1000;
    it.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    it.it_interval.tv_usec = 1000;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it, NULL);

    while(1) {
        counter++;
        time(&t);
        r = ctime(&t);
        printf("Loop %d\n",counter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will typically enter a deadlock after a couple thousand iterations. Now, attach `strace` like so

```
strace -s4096 -p<PID>
```

where `PID` is the program's process id. You'll see the program hang in a call with `FUTEX_WAIT` in the parameters. (I cannot quote the whole line as I currently don't have access to a RHEL4 machine, please excuse that).

Comment: It would be very helpful if this could be scripted somehow. I read the man page of strace but couldn't find a way to print only the current/latest syscall. If that was possible, I could loop on all processes and check for a `futex` call with `FUTEX_WAIT`.

Comment: @Amr Mostafa. `strace -s4096 -p$PID 2>&1 | grep -v -E -e "^Process" -e "^restart_syscall" | head -c12` may get you started. Both the constant `12` and the regular expressions may need some love, but the result seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `/proc/<pid>/syscall`, this is how I ended up implementing a [quick and dirty processes futex(op=FUTEX_WAIT) scanner](https://gist.github.com/722145).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Find all processes that are executing a futex(2) call with op=FUTEX_WAIT
# In some cases this can be helpful in finding deadlock-ed processes.
#

test ! $UID -eq 0 && echo -e "WARNING: Not running as root, only processes for this user are being scanned\n" >&2;
pids=$(ps -u $UID -opid --no-headers)

for pid in $pids; do
        cat /proc/$pid/syscall |

        awk "{if (\$1 == 202 && \$3 == \"0x0\") {
                print $pid
        }}";

        # $1 is the syscall, we compare to 202 which is the futex call
        # See: /usr/include/asm/unistd.h

        # $2 is the 1st param, $3 is the 2nd param, etc
        # We compare the second param to 0x0 which is FUTEX_WAIT
        # See: /usr/include/linux/futex.h
done
```

Answer (score -1):

UNIX guarantees that OS processes never gets in deadlock. No such guarantees are, however, made for user defined processes. As far as I know, there is no direct way of determining whether a process has been deadlocked.

That said, you could determine the process state by `ps  -o pid,uname,command,state,stime,time`. `man ps` shows more detailed explanation on process state codes too.

Comment: There's nothing in UN*X that _guarantees_ OS/kernel processes/threads do not deadlock. If they do it's a bug, admittedly, but the OS/kernel design / API don't make such deadlocks impossible.